# ng-class allows assignment operator. is it a bug or feature?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I recently noticed that `ng-class` allows assignment operator is it a bug or a feature.

`<li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="{active: cat = 'some-text'}">{{cat}}</li>`

correct usage

`<li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="{active: cat == 'some-text'}">{{cat}}</li>`

also look at the [plunk behaviour](https://plnkr.co/edit/xhVw7XyIRVSIBhBJ42di?p=preview)

Allowing assignment operator is a bug or a feature?

Comment: What is `active` in `ng-class`?

Comment: it is just a class to be added when the condition is met

Comment: then that is not right expression. `{'active': cat === 'some-text'}` this is correct and  there `some-text` is just a string and if it matches with the variable `cat` then `active` class will be added to `li` element

Comment: got it. @Mr_Perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raised an issue in GitHub and got a clarification

issue : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16049

issue-comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/16049#issuecomment-308092056

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a JavaScript expression evaluation, instead of a special Angular thing.

```
var x;
console.log(!!(x = 'some-text'));
```

If you see your console, it will always print `true`. Similarly, `ng-class="{active: cat = 'some-text'}"` will always assign the class `active` to the element, since `cat = 'some-text'` will always return `true` as its boolean equivalent.

Also, it is notable that `cat` will be changed to `some-text` in each iteration. This means that your `cats` object will be nothing but an array of `some-text`.

As @Mr_Perfect mentioned in the comments, if you conditionally need to assign `active` to your elements, change `=` to `===`.

Comment: yeah. the entire array changes to `some-text`

Comment: `console.log(x = 'some-text')` prints `some-text` not `true`

Comment: @SibiRaj: What do you want to achieve? Please mention in the question.

Comment: my question is straight forward I think. `ng-class` allows assignment operator is it a feature or bug. so simple.

Comment: @SibiRaj - It is definitely not a bug. Angular evaluates your expression and calculates its boolean equivalent. Based on the boolean value, it assigns the particular class.

Answer (score 1):

It's because, as you assigne a value to `cat` it's evaluated to true because `cat` is not null or undifined

Comment: so its not a bug

Comment: No it's just JavaScript behavior

Answer (score 1):

`{'active': cat === 'some-text'}`  is correct way to add class and there `some-text` is just a string and if it matches with the variable `cat` then `active` class will be added to `li` element

Even you can do like this,

```
ng-class="{(condition) ? 'condition_true_class' : 'condition_false_class'}"
```

**EDIT**

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="{active: cat = 'some-text'}">{{cat}}</li>
```

in this case `cat="some-text"` returns `some-text` string which is always true and `active` class will be added to `li` element and `cat` in `{{}}` becomes `some-text` as you are using assignment operator.

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="{active: cat == 'some-text'}">{{cat}}</li>
```

in this case if `cat` value matches with `some-text` then `active` class will be added to `li` and `cat` value will not change as you are using logical operator `==` or `===`

Comment: my question is that allowing assignment operator is a bug or feature. look at this plunk behaviour https://plnkr.co/edit/xhVw7XyIRVSIBhBJ42di?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use class active wiith `ng-class` try this :

```
<li ng-repeat="cat in cats" ng-class="{'active': cat == 'some-text'}">{{cat}}</li>
```